# Correct closure terminology, or what exactly is called a closure

Tags: javascript

In [this accepted popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/111200/1968972) the closures are explained. I understand the concept and can use it, but my question is rather terminological, look at this simple example:

```
function foo(x) {
  var tmp = 3;

  function bar(y) {
    alert(x + y + (++tmp)); // will alert 16
  }

  bar(10);
}

foo(2);
```

So what exactly should be ***called*** a closure here: `bar`? or `foo`? or `tmp`? Or all of them together?

You see how community wiki is calling `bar` a closure, is that exactly right? Then how do I refer in a conversation to `tmp` and to `foo`? Are they also called closure, or variable inside a closure and closure accessor or whatever else? Or bar is called external closure and foo is internal closure?

Comment: `bar` is the closure, `tmp` is a local variable, `foo` is a function.

Comment: @Afforess every variable is called variable

Comment: Closure is a function + its scope function was created in. Together this is *closure*.

Comment: You haven't actually linked an accepted answer, but the JS tag. Which answer do you mean?

Comment: `foo` is sometimes misnomed as "closure" - as it sets up the *closure scope* for `bar`, and *creates the closure* (`bar`).

Comment: @Bergi I mean exactly the accepted one. Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Bar is a closure as it has closed environment in which tmp value exist which is local variable of foo function. 
Local or private variable can be accesed by inner functions even after the function has return because of the closed environment formed (In which value of local variable of outer function resides), that's why it is called closure, So here Bar is termed as closure but it closes the Environment of Foo.